# Why is Conda having problem using the proxy configured in the environment variables on Windows?

Tags: windows, proxy, environment-variables, conda, miniconda

I'm currently in a kinda special network condition where both google and the conda server could only be accessed through a proxy server. As a conseuqence, I have installed a proxying program and have previously set up the following in my cmd:

```
set http_proxy=127.0.0.1:[a port number]
set https_proxy=127.0.0.1:[a port number]
```

And a test on an attempt to access google with `curl`(which it initially couldn't) proves the configuration to be successful:

```
>curl http://google.com
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

However, conda does not seem to be able to access its sever successfully through the exact same proxy settings:

```
>conda install gazebo
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

ProxyError: Conda cannot proceed due to an error in your proxy configuration.
Check for typos and other configuration errors in any '.netrc' file in your home directory,
any environment variables ending in '_PROXY', and any other system-wide proxy
configuration settings.
```